# jquery calculator deleteing items before a operator. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason when ever I push the divide, multiply, add, or subtract button. What the code should do is if there is something like a operator when you click it it replaces it but instead it replaces anything that is the last letter.

```
$(".Button:eq(2)").click(function(){
    var R1 = $("#Num_View");
    R1.val(R1.val().replace( /[*/+-x]?$/, '-' ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
R1.val(R1.val().replace( /[*/+-x]?$/, '-' ) );
```

to

```
R1.val(R1.val().replace( /[\*\+-x]/, '-' ) );
```

should work.

Since you're already using the replace function, you don't need the `?` (zero or one) and the `$` matches the end of the string, so by removing that you can replace anywhere in your string.

Comment: No it replaced the beginning for some reason. I need it to only replace the end if it is a +,/,-,x. And if there isn't one I need it to still add a minus symbol.

Comment: I see the errors of my ways. I updated the regex to correctly escape with `\\`. You can also checkout http://regexpal.com/ to help you write your own regex's.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should match globally (by adding the `g` flag) without matching the end of the string (without the $ sign). Also, don't forget to escape reserved characters (in your case, that would be *, +, - and /).

The resulting regular expression should look like this:

```
$(".Button:eq(2)").click(function(){
    var R1 = $("#Num_View");
    R1.val(R1.val().replace( /[\*\/\+\-x]/g, '-'));
});
```

Comment: It replaced the thing at the begining not at the end. And it did not add anything if it was not there.

Comment: @CDW Do you have some examples of what the values of `R1.val()` usually look like?